# When switching to pigpiod, which replacement shall I use for gpioSetTimerFunc()?

Tags: pigpio

When still using the pigpio API "directly", I made extensive use of the [gpioSetTimerFunc function](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioSetTimerFunc), just like this:

```
gpioSetTimerFunc (4, 500, OnRDSDataTimerElapsed);
```

After making pigpiod do all the GPIO-related work, I have to replace all pigpio calls with pigpiod ones. However, I can't find a viable replacement for the timed callback in the pigpiod API.

Can anybody plase give me a hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gpioSetTimerFunc](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioSetTimerFunc) calls a function at regular intervals.

There is no equivalent in [pdif2](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html) so you will have to implement another solution.

I suggest you create a new thread using [start_thread](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html#start_thread) and use [time_sleep](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html#time_sleep) within the thread to delay for the regular interval.

For an example see http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_DHTXXD and in particular `pthTriggerThread`.

Comment: Well OK, thank you for your quick and competent answer (despite the fact that it's a pity that this method is not part of pdif2 whereas most other pigpio utility methods are), but I will look into the sourcecode you recommended and watch out for another C/C++ library, which supports timer-driven callbacks.

Comment: OK, I've accomplished my goal by using the Poco library. It contains the `TimerTask` class, which does almost exactly the same as your `gpioSetTimerFunc`, but I had to write a wrapper for it. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132421/how-can-i-use-a-static-c-method-as-a-callback-for-a-poco-timer